# Error when copying sequential dataset to VSAM file

Tags: mainframe, jcl, vsam

I am trying to load a VSAM file with the data present in a sequential file using the below JCL, but I am getting the a JCL Internal error.

```
//TESTJB5 JOB ,,NOTIFY=MURUGAN,REGION=6M                 
//S1 EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                                     
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=A                                   
//INDD DD DSN=MURUGAN.DATASET.FILE1,DISP=SHR             
//OUTDD DD DSN=MURUGAN.TEST.VSAM,UNIT=SYSDA,             
// DCB=(BLKSIZE=27920,LRECL=80,RECFM=FB),                
// DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),SPACE=(TRKS,(1,1))            
//SYSIN DD *                                             
REPRO INFILE(INDD) OUTFILE(OUTDD)                        
/*
```

Comment: At what point do you get the message? Please provide the exact message (copy/paste) including the message code. If you have spool output from the JOB, include all of that please (use the edit link under your question to include all this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems of different magnitudes.

Firstly, the `,,` on the JOB card looks suspicious. It isn't, but it serves absolutely no purpose other than to cause people to think it looks suspicious. You'll save wasted time by removing those double commas entirely.

You have no MSGCLASS on the JOB statement. This (depending on site option) means that you are limiting your chances of receiving diagnostic information.

You have no CLASS on your JOB statement.

I suggest you ask your immediate boss, colleagues, technical support, to show you a sample JOB card which meets the standards at your site.

Your REPRO statement will not work, because you have started it in column one.

What your probable actual problem is, is that you are unaware of how to use a VSAM file (dataset). You may well already have a VSAM file of that name, and you are now creating (without realising it) an ordinary sequential file of the same name. Best guess without further information.